# Multi-window electron application using React/Angular

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, electron

How can I implement a multi-window Electron application using React/Angular, where each window is powered by a separate HTML file?

In typical React/Angular applications, the build process often results in a single HTML file (e.g., index.html). However, for an Electron app, I need to create distinct windows, each with its own HTML file. What steps or configurations are necessary to achieve this separation of HTML files for different windows in an Electron application built with React or Angular?

I tried to use Angular's routing but it was of no use.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple HTML files basically means multiple applications. It doesn't mean you have to create separate apps of course, but it means you have to configure whatever bundler you use to handle each entry files. There's no one-size-fits-all configuration for this, as it depends entirely on the library and how you created your application in the first place.

As an example (I'm speaking with React in mind), let's imagine you want an **app** window and **worker** window. You will need an entry HTML and JS file for each:

```js
src/
├── app/
│   ├── app.js
│   └── app.html
└── worker/
    ├── worker.js
    └── worker.html
```

And you will also create a [`BrowserWindow`](https://BrowserWindow) for each:

```js
const appWindow = new BrowserWindow();
appWindow.loadUrl("http://localhost:3000/index.html"); // Dev

const workerWindow = new BrowserWindow();
workerWindow.loadUrl("http://localhost:3000/worker.html"); // Dev
```

And if for example you use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) as bundler, you will configure two [entry points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/):

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./src/app.js",
    worker: "./src/worker.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/app/app.html",
      filename: "app.html",
      chunks: ["app"],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/worker/worker.html",
      filename: "worker.html",
      chunks: ["worker"],
    })
  ]
};
```

This is just a skeleton of configuration, but it's to show the idea.

---

**In short:** make sure your bundler takes care of all your entry points and you should be good.