# How to load a child browserwindow?

Tags: electron, quasar-framework, quasar

been searching around but can't seem to find any info about it, I am building a Electron app with the help of vue and Quasar. C

Clearly one makes a new browser window in the main process, but where should I point the browserwindow.loadURL() to make it work in both dev and prod? should I be using "process.env.APP_URL"? any attempt using that just load my main window in the child window.

I have a secondWindow .html/.js file in the /src folder.

tried several things with process.env.APP_URL like process.env.APP_URL + "/secondWindow" or process.env.APP_URL + "/#/secondWindow" but none of them are working and at best gets me the main window instead in dev.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-window electron application using React/Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77770559/multi-window-electron-application-using-react-angular)

Comment: It gave me hints to what I might need, but as I use vite and not webpack I guess I need to figure out how to configure vite trough quasar to have multiple entry points..

Answer (score 0):

Suffering from the same problem and trying to solve it for almost one day, I think I finally figured it out how to solve it.

First, route '/' to 'Route.vue'

routes.js:

```
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/Route.vue'),
  }, 
  {
    path: '/your_page_name',
    component: () => import('layouts/ActualPageIWantToLoad.vue'),
  },
```

Second, make 'Route.vue' like this

```
<template></template>

<script setup>
import { onBeforeMount } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
const router = useRouter()

function searchParam(key) {
  return new URLSearchParams(location.search).get(key)
}

onBeforeMount(() => {
  const param = searchParam('page')
  if (param) {
    router.push({ path: `/${param}` })
  }
})
</script>
```

Basically what it does is to get the page information from query string parameter and route.

Finally, in electron-main.js,
you call the URL like this

```
  mainWindow.loadURL(process.env.APP_URL + '?page=your_page_name')
```

This works both for dev and prod.