# how to load a number of react windows when debugging electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

I build electron app by using react

There is many tutorials. So I can easily made simple program.[example react-electron](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate)
[example 2](https://medium.com/@azer.maslow/creating-desktop-applications-with-electron-and-react-b7f81f78c9d5)

I’m wondering when I’m in developing how to attach all component views by hot loading.
example is just one browser example.

If I assume that there is two view, main window and preference window.

then do I need to running 2 react programs?

I think it is may hard to handle if there are many views more than 2 windows.

I tried to find solution but there is not exist what I want.
is there good solution or article about this?

thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-window electron application using React/Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77770559/multi-window-electron-application-using-react-angular)

Comment: @Arkellys that’s nice idea and seem to be what I thought. I try to test it. thank you. It may explain why discord and other apps used bundler.